# Cycles OpenCL on a OS X?

Tags: osx, opencl

I'm trying to get Blender working with OpenCL on a Mac but I get errors during the run (it tries to do compilation first and that fails).

Comment: Could you copy/paste the specific error to your answer?

Comment: ERROR when running on a NVIDIA GPU

[~]$CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=all ~/Downloads/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender 

Device init success
Compiling OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags: 
OpenCL error (GeForce GT 650M): [CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE] : OpenCL Error : Error: Build Program driver returned (10007)
OpenCL error (GeForce GT 650M): OpenCL Warning : clBuildProgram failed: could not build program for 0x1022700 (GeForce GT 650M) (err:-2)
OpenCL error (GeForce GT 650M): [CL_BUILD_ERROR] : OpenCL Build Error : Compiler build log:
Error getting function data from server

Comment: ----

ERROR when running on an Intel Integrated GPU

Device init success
Compiling OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags: 
OpenCL error (HD Graphics 4000): [CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE] : OpenCL Error : Error: Build Program driver returned (10015)
OpenCL error (HD Graphics 4000): OpenCL Warning : clBuildProgram failed: could not build program for 0x1024400 (HD Graphics 4000) (err:-2)
OpenCL error (HD Graphics 4000): [CL_BUILD_ERROR] : OpenCL Build Error : Compiler build log:
Compile Server Error.

OpenCL kernel build output:
Compile Server Error.
OpenCL build failed: errors in console

-----

Comment: I already ran clInfo on my machine to check if the OpenCL runtimes are working, and clInfo works fine. Also, other apps like LuxRenderer works fine using OpenCL

Comment: I m using Blender v2.75a